# Charles Proxy stops WP Emulator internet connection from working

Tags: windows-phone-7, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm trying to use Charles Proxy to debug traffic from the Windows Phone Emulator, but if I run the emulator after starting Charles Proxy, the emulator cannot connect to the internet at all.  The traffic from the emulator is not picked up in the Charles Proxy session window either, but traffic from Chrome on Windows is.

At this stage I just want to get ordinary http working, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used Charles Proxy.

But you can use Fiddler with the emulator

- download from http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
- instructions for wp7 emulator at http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/fiddler-and-wp7-emulator-working/

This works well for me